# Excel chart shows horizontal axis as the same value after pivot refresh

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, charts, debug, axis

I have created a simple clustered column chart to display request volumes (y-axis) over time (x-axis, months). All of that is linked to a little CountIf table that sources data from a PivotTable (as the original raw data is too large and I would end up writing way too many assumptions to make the CountIf work).

All looks fine, but sometimes (not always) when I Refresh-All-Pivots, all the months in the table are shown as January... The fun part is that if I Change Chart Type, the months are displayed normal again... Equally, if I try creating a new chart, the months are displayed normal. However, if I copy-paste the format of my original chart into a new one, the x-axis get messed up and do not go back if I undo the action (Ctrl + Z).

Unless anyone knows an easy fix to this, my thoughts are to either to create a macro to create brand new graphs every time the pivots are refreshed (sounds inflexible...), or expand my CountIfs to capture all the assumptions and source the original date (will take way too long...).